# Is It Legal to Marry a Jew?

Tags: united-states, family-law, marriage, israel

Let's say an Eastern European woman is in Israel on a work visa and a Jewish man, for whatever reason, wants to marry her. Since it is practically speaking illegal to mix in Israel, could they secretly run off to America, and get married? And if so, would that marriage be recognized in Israel, even though they could not get legally married in Israel itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, there is no prohibition against a Jewish man marrying an Eastern European woman in Israel. If they are both Jewish, the marriage can be performed in Israel. If they are not the same religion, then if they get married in Israel, the government will not recognize the marriage. However, Israel recognizes inter-faith marriages performed outside Israel. The marriage does not have to be secret, and it can be performed in Cyprus as well as America.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to marry in a different country and then return to Israel. The marriage will be legal.

Comment: Hello, MindYB. Welcome the the law.stackexchange. I recommend you take the [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), as we are a little different from other sites. Notably, we are not a forum, but a question-and-answer site. Your post (in our nomenclature, an "answer") is being downvoted because it does not answer the question posed above. Commentary should be restricted to comments (which are unlocked when one's reputation reaches 10).

Comment: ok I corrected my answer

Comment: @MindYB Another quirk of this site is that we ask that questions not be asked in the Answer field. You have a new question. Use the "Ask Question" button and post the same text separately as a new query.

Comment: One other quirk is that people generally prefer answers to include citations to the relevant law, rather than just users' unsupported assertions of what the law is, which are indistinguishable from guesses.